# SQL query not selecting two tables?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, figuring things out and loving it! I try to select two tables and I can't figure out why the output is not as expected.

The UITV_CODE are numbers and now I see the exact same output as VAKGROEP, the output of UITV_CODE should be different. I suspect something is going wrong with selecting two tables. Anyone has any idea?

```
SELECT
    UITVOERDERS.UITV_CODE,
    UITVOERDERS.VAKGROEP,
    UITV_CONTRACTS.CONTRACTNR,
    UITV_CONTRACTS.DAT_STOP
FROM 
    UITVOERDERS,
    UITV_CONTRACTS
WHERE VAKGROEP LIKE 'S%' AND DAT_STOP IS null

ORDER BY UITV_CODE
```

Comment: When you want to select data from tables that have some kind of relationship between then, a better approach is to use JOIN syntax, rather than " .... FROM table1, table2 WHERE ....".  When you use JOIN, you then need to specify the columns that form the relationship between the tables.  eg. " .... FROM UITVOERDERS o JOIN UITV_CONTRACTS c ON o.<relationship column> = c.<relationship column> ....".  If, as you say, you are new to SQL, I'd suggest that you do a little bit of reading on the SELECT syntax for your particular RDBMS, focusing on JOIN instructions

Comment: Always show a (sample of)  expected input and output. The sentence "The UITV_CODE are numbers and now I see the exact same output as VAKGROEP, the output of UITV_CODE should be different." is currently being ignored, because you do not show sample data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 30 UITVOERDERS and 20 UITV_CONTRACTS one would combine everything, 30 x 20 = 600 records and return only those with the WHERE condition.
So if there are 25 UITVOERDERS with UITVOERDERS.VAKGROEP starting with 'S' and 4 UITV_CONTRACTS with DAT_STOP IS null, the 25 x 4 = 100 records shown.

For running contracts, not yet stopped, I would expect:

```
SELECT
    U.UITV_CODE,
    U.VAKGROEP,
    C.CONTRACTNR,
    C.DAT_STOP
FROM 
    UITVOERDERS U,
    UITV_CONTRACTS C
WHERE C.UITV_CODE = U.UITV_CODE
    AND U.VAKGROEP LIKE 'S%' AND C.DAT_STOP IS null
ORDER BY U.UITV_CODE
```

Which could be written as

```
SELECT
    U.UITV_CODE,
    U.VAKGROEP,
    C.CONTRACTNR,
    C.DAT_STOP
FROM 
    UITVOERDERS U
LEFT JOIN UITV_CONTRACTS C ON C.UITV_CODE = U.UITV_CODE
WHERE U.VAKGROEP LIKE 'S%' AND C.DAT_STOP IS null
ORDER BY U.UITV_CODE
```

If the contract links to the uitvoerder.